# Adding an integer to session-stored integer

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I'm writing a skill in python that stores an integer in the session as '**mor_score**', seen below:

```
{
  "session": {
    "sessionId": "SessionId.REDACTED",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.REDACTED"
    },
    "attributes": {
        "mor_score": 0
    },
```

One of my intents attempts to add a value to **mor_score**, but I can't quite figure out how to do so.  Code for the intent show below:

```
def choice_one(intent, session):
    card_title = "Add It Up"
    reprompt_text = None
    should_end_session = False
    if intent['slots']['ChoiceOneSlot']['value'] == 'Red':
        mscore = session.get('attributes').get('mor_score') # currently a value of 0
        session_attributes = {'mor_score': mscore +=2} # trying to add 2
        speech_output = "<speak>Okay, you choose red.</speak>"
    elif intent['slots']['ChoiceOne']['value'] == 'blue':
        speech_output = "<speak>Yes, you choose blue.</speak>"
    else:
        speech_output = "<speak>Try again with an acceptable answer.</speak>"
    return build_result(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
        card_title, speech_output, reprompt_text, should_end_session))
```

I know how to return the results back into the Alexa session, but I'm clearly missing the process by which a number can be added to the variable before it's returned.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**  The following code sorted me out!

```
mscore = session.get('attributes').get('mor_score')
mscore +=2
session_attributes = {'mor_score': mscore}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mscore += 2` is a statement in Python - it absolutely cannot be used as part of an expression.  You either need to put this on a line by itself (and then use just `mscore` in the expression), or use `mscore + 2` in the expression.  The two approaches differ in the value that `mscore` is left with afterwards, but that doesn't matter here because you don't use it afterwards.

Comment: Worked a charm, thanks!  I'll be passing this value back into the session and calling it later, but I think I've written it out properly.
`mscore = session.get('attributes').get('mor_score')
mscore +=2
session_attributes = {'mor_score': mscore}`